# Solving an inequality to get a bound

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Say $\eta=h\lambda=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$. Also $h>0$ and $Re(\lambda)<0$. Is it possible to get a bound for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ from the following inequality and if so, what would that be?
$$\left|\frac{1+(1-\theta)\eta}{1-\theta\eta}\right|<1$$

I tried to come up with something using the usual rules for  complex numbers and I got to
$$\left(\frac{(x^2+y^2)\theta^2-(x^2+y^2+2x)\theta+(1+x)}{(x^2+y^2)\theta^2-2x\theta+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)\theta^2-2x\theta+1}\right)^2<1$$

How to proceed from here?

If I didn't decompose the $\eta$ then I would get
$$2\theta\eta-\eta-2<0<-\eta$$
from which at some point using the fact that $Re(\lambda)<0$ (to change the inequality sign), I get to $$\theta>\frac{1}{h\lambda}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Am I right here?

Comment: The inequality $2\theta\eta-\eta-2<0<-\eta$ is non-sense. It is impossible to compare complex numbers (with zero). By the way - what is $\theta?$

Comment: @user376343 yes I know. I was just using the reasoning (or at least I thought I was) $Re(\lambda)<0$ as is done in p. 2 of http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/478578_Chapter_4.pdf

Comment: yes, already said in the problem. Should be in some sub-interval of $(0,1)$. Also in the last line, $\lambda$ denotes only the real part of it, as it is in the paper (I think)

Comment: I have found $\theta>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{Re (\eta)}{|\eta|}$ (it is without guarantee :) ) But sorry, I do not have time at this moment to edit my solution. If nobody does it within 30 hours, I can return to it.

Comment: $|\eta|^2$ in denominator

Comment: @BernhardListing  Simplify the second equation to get $(2x^2+2y^2)\theta-x^2-y^2-2x > 0$ which results in $\theta > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the assumptions: $1-\theta \eta \neq 0.$ Therefore, the inequality $\left|\frac{1+(1-\theta)\eta}{1-\theta\eta}\right|<1$ is equivalent to
$$\left|1+(1-\theta)\eta\right|<|{1-\theta\eta}|$$
or $$|(1+\eta) -\theta \eta|<|1-\theta \eta| \tag{1}$$
Recall that the inequality $|a-z|<|b-z|$ defines a half plane delimited by the bissector of the segment with extremal points $a,b.$

In the given situation, $a=1+\eta,\ b=1$ and $z=\theta \eta.$
Our $z$ walks on a half line which lies in the above mentionned half plane.

To find a bound for $\theta,$ I use a brute-force nonelegant method.
$$\begin{align}(1) \iff &(x_z-x_a)^2+(y_z-y_a)^2<(x_z-x_b)^2+(y_z-y_b)^2\\
\iff &2x_z(x_b-x_a)+2y_z(y_b-y_a)<x_b^2-x_a^2+y_b^2-y_a^2\\ 
& \vdots\\
\iff & 2\theta Re(\eta)^2+2\theta Im(\eta)^2>Re(\eta)^2+Im(\eta)^2 + Re(\eta)\end{align}
$$
from where the result $$\theta>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{Re (\eta)}{|\eta|^2}.$$